# Which of methods of adding many strings to StringBuilder is faster?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a StringBuilder and I need to add in It many short strings. There are two ways at least. First is adding each string separately:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
sb.Append (str1);
sb.Append (str2);
.....
sb.Append (strN);
```

The second is adding all strings together:

```
sb.Append (string.Concat (str1, str2, ..., strN);
```

Which of them is faster and preferable fo use? 
P.S.: That operation will be executing many times in my program (in cycle) and I don't know, should I to create so many strings via string.Concat so as they will not be used anymore.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking on this?

Comment: How about doing your own benchmark?

Answer (score 2):

I would say the first one, because the second one is creating a temporary `string` for the `Concat`.

Let's see the worse scenario:

> x == sb.Length;
> y == Sum(str 1-n Length)
>
> sb has space for y - 1 characters.
>
> In the first case you'll copy around: `y - 1` characters to sb from the strings, then `x + y - 1` from the old sb buffer to a new sb buffer then the last `1` character. So `x + 2y - 2 + 1` characters, so `x + 2y - 1` characters.
>
> In the second case the Concat buffer is of the right size, so you copy around `y` characters from the strings to the Concat buffer plus `x` from the old to the new sb buffer (because thanks to the single Append the sb knows he has to resize before appending), plus `y` from the Concat buffer to the new sb buffer. So `x + 2y`. The first method should wins by `1` character.

But if you really need to make it faster:

```
int totalLength = str1.Length + str2.Length...

sb.EnsureCapacity(sb.Length + totalLength);

sb.Append(str1);
sb.Append(str2);
sb.Append(str3);
```

and so on.

In this way you copy around `x + y` characters.

You first ensure the `sb` has enough capacity and then begin adding the strings.

**But we are speaking of premature optimization, unless your program does this things "by the thousand".**

Answer (score 1):

As ever, performance shouldn't be based on guesswork - you should test these things. In particular, it may well be affected by:

- The framework version you're using
- The number of strings (N)
- The size of strings
- The *order* of the strings (big ones first or small ones first?)
- Probably many other things I've forgotten about

I'd *expect* `String.Concat` to be faster here *if you didn't need the `StringBuilder` otherwise*, as it can work out the *exact* buffer size required, allocate it once, then copy. `StringBuilder` may need to reallocate multiple times. The downside is that if N is large it will also create an array. EDIT: I originally misread the question, not spotting that the result of `String.Concat` was being used in another `Append` operation. Can you write the *whole* operation in a single `String.Concat` call rather than mixing `StringBuilder` and `String.Concat`.

But yes, basically you should:

- Decide how fast you actually need it to be
- Write the most readable code
- Benchmark it
- Change to other code only if it's not fast enough